# React Native TextInput doesn't increase height at correct content length

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

I am trying to implement a multiline expanding text input using react native elements and react native but I can't seem to get it to function properly.  The behavior is shown in the following screenshots:

As you can  see here, the text has is clearly more than one line, but the text input has not expanded.

[image]

Whenever I enter a few more characters, it expands a little bit but it expands down into the keyboard.

[image]

Adding another line doesn't expand the keyboard:

[image]

Not until I add a few more characters until the newest line is half the width of the text input does the input expand

[image]

Here is the code I am using for the text input:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent', height: Math.max(45, this.state.viewHeight)}}>
<Input
          containerStyle={{marginVertical: 0, width:300, marginLeft: 10}}
          inputStyle={[styles.textInput, {height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}]}
          multiline
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
          keyboardAppearance="dark"
          placeholder=""          
          onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
            if (this.state.height <= (35*6)){
            this.setState({
               height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
              viewHeight: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height })
            }
          }}
          onChangeText={(message) => { this.setState({message})
        }}
```

Here's the code for my text input style:

```
textInput: {
      paddingHorizontal: 12,
      width: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      marginLeft: -4,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      marginTop: 5,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'lightgrey',
      borderRadius: 25,
    },
```

It seems to be that that the content size change event is triggering at the wrong time, is there any way I could set it to only trigger when a new line is a specific length and expand up instead of down into the keyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got it working, I had to update to the expo 0.55 React Native sdk as I think they implemented the autogrow input after .54.  I then had to switch from using a react native elements input to just the react native text input as the RNE one doesn't appear to have autogrow implemented.  Lastly I had to change my height settings, if you set a definite height like I did `height: {35}` it won't grow, so instead I had to use `minheight` for both the input and the view that the input was in  so that they could grow together.

Comment: for me what helped was definitely 'minHeight', thanks a lot